# Query notifications

Tags: java, oracle, hsqldb

I have a program that needs to perform a 'SELECT' on a database: HSQLDB
and then every time information changes, I would like to get a notifications of the query change - that is a DELETE / INSERT / UPDATE into the query results table.

my question is - this seems like an awfully basic requirement and yet I haven't found a solution for this. Does this concept have a formal name.

I know about CQN in oracle but it has some disadvantages.

Here are some possible ways I am considering to acheive my requirement:

1. Use oracle's CQN - It is not perfect, and also I don't want to use oracle - because in memory gives me better performance.
2. Implement the mechanism into HSQLDB - since it is open source. But it has many cases.

Are there DATABASES that support this?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can implement DML triggers on tables you want to be notified about. You can use `dbms_email` package in these triggers to get email notifications. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1):

With HSQLDB, you can use TRIGGER definitions on each table used in the query to notify the DELETE, INSERT AND UPDATE changes as they occur. At that point, you can execute the SELECT again for updated results.